# Restrict Matlab's parallel toolbox from using all cores

Tags: parallel-processing, matlab

Is there a possible way to deny Matlab access to all cores? There are 8 on the machine at present, but I want to reduce Matlab's usage to 3 per user so that one user doesn't start a job on all 8, slowing down others in the process.

I don't have a distributed computing server license... just plain old parallel proc toolbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to enforce a strict limit from within MATLAB, but you can set the "[ClusterSize](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/clustersize.html)" property of the local scheduler. Unfortunately, this must be done per user. Other than that, you would need to use an OS function, but I'm not sure if such a thing exists.

Answer (score 2):

You can voluntarily restrict the number of workers used for a job by setting the `MaximumNumberOfWorkers` property of the job object before you submit it.

```
jobMgr = findResource(...appropriate parameters for your job manager here...);
job = createJob(jobMgr);

set(job, 'MaximumNumberOfWorkers', 3);

% create some tasks and add them to the job here

submit(job);
waitForState(job, 'finished');
results = getAllOutputArguments(job);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say per user, are you implying that multiple users are able to submit to this machine at once?  This would certainly complicate things by I have some example code that might reveal some commands you are not familiar with that will help you reach your goal.

This is some code I use to use as many cores as possible, up to 8.

ncores = feature('numCores');
nworkers = min(8,ncores);

Comment: yes... there is no system wide job manager running. It's just a server with matlab installed for all users. So each user can start their own instance of matlab and request a max of 8 cores, as permitted by the local scheduler. when more than one user starts doing this, it becomes a problem.